# How to know facebook wall post shared or canceled using facebook app in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

Let me clear my question . M using facebook native application to post on wall using this code

```
    public void sendToFB()
{
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
String _mPostText=
         "{\"name\":\"My Test Image\"," + "\"href\":\"" +
          "http://www.google.com" + "\"," +
          "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"" +
          "http://www.google.com/logos/mucha10-hp.jpg" +
          "\",\"href\":\"" + "http://www.google.com" + "\"}]" + "}";
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,_mPostText );
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"), 100);

}
```

This is working perfect. Below is the snap shot of result.
[image]

M setting OnActivityResult for this intent.

Code is below

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestcode ==100){//do something
        }
        }
```

}

My problem is that i want to perform action when facebook post is share. 
Here if facebook post is cancelled than also onActivityResult is performing same action.
How can i know that facebook post is share or cancel?
Kindly suggest me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A well written activity should return `resultCode==RESULT_CANCEL` if it is cancelled. Are you saying it is not the case?

Comment: @rds In both cases its returning resultcode=RESULT_OK..

Comment: This might not be much help, but I think the JavaScript approach for sharing with Facebook does the same thing. Facebook tents to not want apps to know if the user shared or not. You can often download shared locked content by canceling the share action once prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android SDK instead of the application.

The SDK is open-source, in case it has the same bug, you can fix it.

Comment: using graph api i can also handle this. but due to some reasons i hav to use native facebook application only.